# Compare Values of Database and Json and display result

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, fmdb, sbjson

I am creating a table with multiple columns. In the left column I want to get the indicator name which is stored in a database and I have to check that the indicator id in database and in json (API) matches and then display the name in that column. I have tried some code

In view load method I take values from database and store it in an array

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    indicatorName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *path = appDelegate.databasePath;
    FMDatabase *db = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:path];
    [db open];

    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Topic AS t INNER JOIN TopicIndicators AS ti ON t.Id = ti.TopicId INNER JOIN Indicators AS i ON ti.IndicatorID = i.Id"];// WHERE t.Id = %ld", (long)self.Tid];

    FMResultSet *fresult = [db executeQuery:sql];

    while ([fresult next])
    {

        TopicModel *topicModel = [[TopicModel alloc]init];

        topicModel.TId = [fresult intForColumn:@"Id"];
        topicModel.TTopicType = [fresult stringForColumn:@"TopicType"];
        topicModel.TCode = [fresult stringForColumn:@"Code"];
        topicModel.TName = [fresult stringForColumn:@"Name"];

        topicModel.IId = [fresult intForColumn:@"Id"];
        topicModel.ICodeId = [fresult stringForColumn:@"CodeId"];
        topicModel.IName = [fresult stringForColumn:@"Name"];
        topicModel.INotes = [fresult stringForColumn:@"Notes"];

        topicModel.TIId = [fresult intForColumn:@"Id"];
        topicModel.TITopicId = [fresult intForColumn:@"TopicId"];
        topicModel.TIIndicatorID = [fresult intForColumn:@"IndicatorId"];

        [indicatorName addObject:topicModel];
    }

    [db close];

    mainTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self callPages];

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Compare By", nil);

    XCMultiTableView *tableView = [[XCMultiTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 5.0f, 5.0f)];
    tableView.leftHeaderEnable = YES;
    tableView.datasource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

}
```

In request finished method I am taking values from json and assigning the values in appropriate columns.

```
-(void) requestFinished: (ASIHTTPRequest *) request
{
    NSString *theJSON = [request responseString];

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *jsonDictionary = [parser objectWithString:theJSON error:nil];
    headData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *head = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    leftTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *left = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    rightTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSMutableArray *dictionary in jsonDictionary)
    {
        Model *model = [[Model alloc]init];

        model.cid = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"cid"]intValue];
        model.iid = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"iid"]intValue];
        model.yr = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"yr"]intValue];
        model.val = [dictionary valueForKey:@"val"];

        [head addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", model.yr]];
        [left addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", model.iid]];
        [mainTableData addObject:model];
    }

    NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:head];
    headData = [[orderedSet array] mutableCopy];

    NSOrderedSet *orderedSet1 = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:left];
    NSMutableArray *arrLeft = [[orderedSet1 array] mutableCopy];


    //remove duplicate enteries from header array
    [leftTableData addObject:arrLeft];


    NSMutableArray *right = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLeft.count; i++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int j = 0; j < headData.count; j++)
        {
            /* NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.iid == %ld", [[arrLeft objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
             NSArray *filteredArray = [mainTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];*/
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.iid == %ld AND SELF.yr == %ld", [[arrLeft objectAtIndex:i] intValue], [[headData objectAtIndex:j] intValue]];
            NSArray *filteredArray = [mainTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            TopicModel *topicModel = [[TopicModel alloc]init];
            for (int k = 0; k < arrLeft.count; k++)
            {
                if (topicModel.IId == arrLeft[k])
                {
                    [newArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",topicModel.IName]];
                }
            }
            if([filteredArray count]>0)
            {
                Model *model = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];
                [array addObject:model.val];
            }
        }
        [right addObject:array];
    }
    [rightTableData addObject:right];
}
```

I am using FMDB, ASIHTTPRequest, SBJSON, XCMultisortTableView.

Please do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are creating new `TopicModel` object which is empty! You need to use the one which you set in your `viewDidLoad:` method.

```
for (int k = 0; k < arrLeft.count; k++) {

    if ([(TopicModel *)indicatorName[k] IId] == [arrLeft[k] integerValue]) {

         [newArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(TopicModel *)indicatorName[k] IName]];
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives error Bad receiver type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')

Comment: I assumed it is a string comparison but you are comparing long. Updated the answer!

Comment: Still getting error [__NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance .

Comment: what is the type of your `topicModel.IId`?

Comment: I guess that in this loop I won't get values in topicModel. I am confused how to get those values from view load method

Comment: Still the problem exists that topicModel doesn't get any values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75172/discussion-between-burhanuddin-sunelwala-and-itaws).